# Connection refused with sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, portforwarding

First off, thanks to all users because I learnt a lot reading questions and answers on this website.

I'm starting to learn Python and I'm trying to send information of a PC over internet through sockets to another PC. It all worked great when I connected two computers of my localhost. However, I'm trying to connect with a friend's computer and I can't do it. I know (thanks to previous topics on this page) that the server needs to forward a port to his own computer. My friend already did that and, me as a client and he as a server, we haven't been able to connect.

I'd like to show you my really simple code because I'm sure I mistaken something I can't figure out what.

This is the client script:

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(("Public IP of server",9990))

if True:
    print "Conexion establecida"
while True:
    mensaje = raw_input("Mensaje a enviar: ")
    if mensaje == "close":
        break
    else:
        s.send(mensaje)
print "Mensaje enviado."
s.close()
```

And this is the server script:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("",9990))
s.listen(1)
sc, addr = s.accept()
print "Conexion establecida con ", str(addr[0])
while True:
    recibido = sc.recv(1024)
    if recibido == "close":
        break
    print str(addr[0]) + " dice: ", recibido    
    sc.close()
s.close()
```

The client script connect with the public ip the server and, if true, let the user send a message. The server scripts just receives the message and prints it. I hope it is enough to no not make you lose a lot of time. Lot of thanks for reading me!

Comment: Does you or your friend have a firewall which is dropping your packets? I'd start by trying a simple ``ping <friends ip>`` then doing a ``traceroute`` to see where communication is being stalled. This really isn't a Python question, but rather a networking question.

Comment: I reccomend using Autobahn instead of pure sockets. You can bind events to: onMessage, onConnect, onDisconnect, et-c, instead of listening on a port. Another thing: I host a personal website; to have that personal website displayed to friends family, et-c, you have to not only port forward on your router, but also on your modem. Further details about you and your friend's broadband setup are required.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering me. I pointed the IP towards my own router and forwarded a port to get the info to my own computer. After that, I pinged and tracerouted my public IP and it passed the test. So, I opened two terminals and executed the server and the client. While the server is opening without problems, the client script prints me the error number 111: connection refused.